# How to show autocomplete of a input bar without type?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

As you know, `<input>` has an attribute `autocomplete`, if it's set to `on`, it will remember what you type, and when you type again in this input bar, after you type a few letter, it will autocomplete the remembered words.
I'd like to know, can I get the autocomplete words without a type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean access a browser's autocomplete words from Javascript or similar? Technically no, as this would be a security flaw, and malicious web pages could suck out all of your personal information. In reality there are security flaws in browsers and I've seen IE6, IE7 and Safari are vulnerable to an attack which reveals a browser's autocomplete values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the options for auto complete, you can use jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var items = [ {text: "Autocomplete 1"}, 
               {text: "auto 2"}, 
               {text: "auto 3"} ]

$("#list").autocomplete(items, {
  matchContains: true,
  minChars: 0,
  formatItem: function(item) 
    { return item.text; }
    }
  );
  });
```

and then something like this on the element:

```
$(".auto_complete").focus(function() { $(this).trigger("keydown") })
```

Comment: I don't want this...input bar has a autocomplete, you know that, do you?